# Is it possible to move photos from Windows 10 mobile to Mac?

Tags: sync, windows-10-mobile, phone-connector-mac

In the past I used the Windows Phone for Mac app to move data between my Windows Phone and my Mac. Months ago it was removed from the Mac App Store.

How can I move data (like photos, etc.) from my Lumia 830 with Windows 10 Mobile and my Mac running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3?

N.B.: I know I can use online solution like OneDrive, Dropbox etc. but I have to move a lot of photos and it would take too much time. Also, removing the SD card is inconvenient for everyday activity since I have to switch off and open the phone every time.

Comment: *Best* solution would be to use something other than a Mac... :P. Does Mac have some sort of File Explorer like Windows does that you could view the SD card files?

Comment: @RareNCool in the question I specified that I don't want to use the SD card everytime.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant could you hook it up with USB and see the files on the SD? I know you can with Windows...

Comment: @RareNCool yes, it's possible.

Comment: Well then unless there's issues with that, I'd say that's a solution.

Comment: @RareNCool not a very comfy one, especially for everyday sync. I stated in the original question that I already knew this possibility, I was looking for a better one.

Comment: If you don't want to use a cloud service, don't want to take out the micro-SD and don't want to hook it up with USB, what ***do*** you want to do?

Comment: @RareNCool I'm not here to argue, my question is pretty clear: I already know that I can use cloud (but it's slowly for many pics) or take out the SD (but it's unpractical for everyday), I asked *if* there is a way to move photos like I used to do with Windows Phone for Mac App when it was still available, connecting the phone directly to the Mac.

Comment: I'm not attempting to argue. Using USB with some sort of file explorer is the closest you can get to the previous way, so I'm not understanding what you're wanting to do if not use USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Nokia Photo Transfer for mac . I dont have an official link .
This might help [Nokia photo transfer](http://m.en.softonic.com/app/nokia-photo-transfer/mac)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your phone to the Mac with a charging cable. Unlock your phone, and the Mac should respond and you would be able to open file explorer to view all of your files. You would also be able to import all photos to your Mac. If not, just save all the files.

Let me know if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried, the Photos app opened, but it didn't find any photos in my phone (the photos are on my SD card).